How to refresh a observable collection in parent when it's updated in sub page viewmodel?
I have a Maui application with tabs. On the DashboardMainPage, items are displayed in a CollectionView. From this page, I can navigate to a subpage (GoalsPage) where all items can be seen in more detail. In GoalsPage, I can navigate to another subpage (CreateGoalPage) where new goals can be saved to the local database.
The navigation flow (using shell navigation, Shell.Current.GoToAsync):
DashboardMainPage -> GoalsPage -> CreateGoalPage
public partial class DashboardMainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    // The repository to handle CRUD to local db
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public ObservableCollection<Goal> Goals { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Goal>();

    public DashboardMainViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    // This is called from OnAppearing of DashboardMainPage
    internal async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        if (IsInitialized)  // Prevents LoadDataAsync running multiple times when navigate on and navigate back from subpage
        {
            return;
        }

        await LoadDataAsync();
    }
    
    private async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
        Goals.Clear();

        var goalsTask =  _unitOfWork.Goal.GetAllAsync(_ => _.Completed == false);
        Goals.AddRange(goalsTask);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task GoToGoalsPage() => await NavigationService.GoToAsync(nameof(GoalsPage));
}

public partial class GoalsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public ObservableCollection<Goal> OnGoingGoals { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Goal>();
    public ObservableCollection<Goal> CompletedGoals { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Goal>();

    public GoalsViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;     
    }
    
    // This is called from OnAppearing of DashboardMainPage
    internal async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        if (IsInitialized) // Prevents LoadDataAsync running multiple times when navigate on and navigate back from subpage
        {
            return;
        }

        await LoadDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
        OnGoingGoals.Clear();
        CompletedGoals.Clear();

        var goals = await _unitOfWork.Goal.GetAllAsync();
        var completed = goals.Where(_ => _.IsCompleted).OrderByDescending(_ => _.Completed.Date);

        OnGoingGoals.AddRange(goals.Where(_ => !_.IsCompleted));
        CompletedGoals.AddRange(completed);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task GoToGoalCreatePage()
    {
        var goal = new Goal();
        
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> {
            { nameof(Goal), goal }
        };
        await NavigationService.GoToAsync(nameof(GoalCreatePage), parameters);
    }
}

[QueryProperty(nameof(Goal), nameof(Goal))]
[QueryProperty(nameof(IsEdit), nameof(IsEdit))]
public partial class GoalCreateViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    // The repository to handle CRUD to local db
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Goal _goal;

    public GoalCreateViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task Save()
    {
        var savedGoal = await _unitOfWork.Goal.SaveAsync(Goal);
        if (savedGoal is not null)
        {
            // should I trigger here a weakreference to call item in the both parent vms?
            
            // Navigate back to GoalsPage
            await NavigationService.GoBackAsync();
        }
    }
}

QUESTIONS
When a new goal is added in the sub-sub page, how is it possible to update the two parent pages?

Should I use weakreference (seems against mvvm)?
The fact I am using twice the same list, is there a way I can make a single observable collection which can be reached in all VM? (DashboardMainViewModel , GoalsViewModel and CreateGoalViewModel) and when locally is saved I could just add as Goals.Add(NewGoal)? Should it be part of the BaseViewModel?


You can see official sample: create a default xamarin forms project(choose Flyout)(Its code also works with MAUI). You can refer to the settings of the refresh logic in it.

If you put an observable collection in a singleton and use dependency injection, then, all pages will have read/write access to the same data. For the master-detail transition, you can pass keys to that observable collection.

@StephenQuan Do you recommend lets say create a ViewDataStoreService which holds all the observable collections? And when I do a crud operation on the local db I update the observable collection also in that service so all pages which are using this will be updated?

@Zoltán sorry, I missed the fact that it was backed by a local db. That pretty much eliminates the need to whole a lot of data in ObservableCollection, just fetch it from the db again. You only need to have a mechanism to know that any fetch data is stale and needs to be fetched again. You can broadcast changes via properties or events in a singleton service or you could use the WeakReferenceMessenger.

@StephenQuan thanks. Some pages have multiple collections means multiple get from the repisitory. What do you think about having a AppRefreshService which would hold if specific local table has any changes so when OnAppeared called which has been initilaized already before would check a dictionary to store if that get method should be called to refresh the data? I do not wish to refresh all the time everything when a little change happens only that collection which is related.

@Zoltán For the most simplest implementation, you merely need to broadcast, say a WeakReferenceMessenge that contains the index of the updated record. Then, any ObservableCollectoin that matches will need to be marked as invalid as well. No need to trigger a fetch, in fact, if you have a lazy load (delay load) scenario that would be best.

There is another option available. You can create an IDateStore and prepare its data before moving to a new Content Page and receive it in another viewmodel. Here is a sample code for reference.
  public interface IDataStore
        {
            void AddCalender(CalendarEvent item);
            CalendarEvent GetCalendarEvent();
            
        }

//implementation 
 public class DataStore : IDataStore
    {
        private CalendarEvent calendarEvent;
        public void AddCalender(CalendarEvent item)
        {
            calendarEvent = item;
        }
       public CalendarEvent GetCalendarEvent()
        {
            return calendarEvent;
        }

//register singleton
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataStore, DataStore>();

//Prepare data for another viewmodel
var dataStore = serviceProvider.GetService<IDataStore>();
                    dataStore?.AddCalender(item);
            var popup = serviceProvider.GetService<EventDetailPopup>();
                popupService.ShowPopup(popup);

//Received another viewmodel
    public partial class EventDetailsViewModel:BaseViewModel
        {
            [ObservableProperty]
            private CalendarEvent item;
     
            public EventDetailsViewModel(IDataStore dataStore)
            { 
                Item = dataStore.GetCalendarEvent();
            }


In my app I have some collections which are the same, but using by different pages/vms. This collection is fetched from local db every single time when the current page needs.
Am I right that your solution suggest to have one singleton collection and when I save to local db i should add the item to this singleton collection as well? With this the collection which is used across the app has a reference to the singleton collection, isnt breaking MVVM?

@ZoltánOnce data is added to the local database, it should also be updated in the Collection. I don't think this breaks MVVM as long as it is managed properly. VIewModel is not bind with any view or context.
